# How can i run class in background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I create an application that retrieve data from websites(that's not mine) and save to core data. I want to create the notification when the new record have been inserted to my core data. I think the retrieve data method and add objects method should be run on the background but how can i do that? any sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You really should build a basic understanding of multithreaded programming before you jump into this, and that's rather a bigger subject than we can reasonably cover in an answer. Start by reading Apple's documentation on the topic:

- [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH1-SW1)
- [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't easy to do. Using Core Data in a background thread requires you to have a separate context for that thread. I'd suggest starting out by reading the [Core Data Concurrency Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html). Also read the guides that Caleb linked to.

Once you figure out how to get your background context running, you'll most likely want to subscribe to the [NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification) to update the UI on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(yourMethod:) withObject:];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform an async request [wich won't be performed on the main thread], and you will be notified about request completion/error/timeout in a **delegate** method, based on the library you are using.

I have experience with [RestKit](http://restkit.org/), you will find plenty of examples in [the repository](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/tree/master/Examples).

Answer (score 0):

You mention creating a notification when inserting data into CoreData. Couldn't you just watch for the notifications sent by CoreData, like NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification?